# $\chi : \text{Hom}(M,A) \otimes \text{Hom}(A,N) \to \text{Hom}(M,N) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M,N$ be $A$-modules.

Consider the map.

$$\chi : \text{Hom}(M,A) \otimes \text{Hom}(A,N) \to \text{Hom}(M,N) $$
$$f \otimes g \mapsto g \circ f   $$

If $M,N$ are projective I do know that $\chi$ is a isomorphism. Eric Wofsey [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790971/36248) that in general $\chi$ is not injective.

Can we classify rings such that $\chi$ is an isomorphism? Clearly any field is ok.

Comment: Generally, it's better to ask a followup question as a new question, rather than editing your old question.  Include a link back to the original question for context.  (As for the answer to the followup question, I think the answer should be only rings for which all modules are projective, but I have to think a bit more.)

Comment: Actually, $\chi$ isn't even always an isomorphism for projective modules; you must assume at least one of them is finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Take $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $M=N=A/(x)$.  Then $\operatorname{Hom}(M,A)\cong M$, generated by the map $f:1\mapsto x$, and $\operatorname{Hom}(A,M)\cong M$, generated by the map $g:1\mapsto 1$.  The tensor product $\operatorname{Hom}(M,A)\otimes \operatorname{Hom}(A,M)$ is then also isomorphic to $M$, generated by $f\otimes g$.  But $g\circ f=0$, so $\chi$ is not injective.

Comment: I edited. I'd love another comment from you.